# Extract piece of lambda for expression in select

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-entities, expression, expression-trees

I can extract and reuse entire expression like that:

```
Expression<Func<User, int>> userExpression = x => x.Roles.Count()
```

but is it possible to extract some how only `x.Roles.Count()` part and use that in context of `Expression<Func<User, T>>`

Thing that I am trying to achieve is reuse that part across different selects like:

```
users.Select(x => new AnotherClass { RoleCount = roleCountPartOfExpression})
```

and

```
users.Select(x => new OneMoreAnotherClass 
              { 
                 AnotherProperty = roleCountPartOfExpression
              });
```

So what `roleCountPartOfExpression` is supposed to be in this case should be supported in LINQ to Entities (so creating a method where I will pass User where will be `return user.Roles.Count()` will not work) also I cant create expression for select like `Expression<Func<User, AnotherClass>>` because in that case I will need to create `Expression<Func<User, OneMoreAnotherClass>>` and that will break my "reusability" goal.

Comment: You can easily make a `Func<User, int>` without the expression, and pass in `x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you compile to a `Func<User, int>`, you can call it in other areas like so:

```
Expression<Func<User, int>> userExpression = x => x.Roles.Count();

Func<User,int> userFunc = userExpression.Compile();

users.Select(x => new AnotherClass { RoleCount = userFunc(x) });
```

Or simply define as a `Func` to begin with:

```
Func<User,int> userFunc = x => x.Roles.Count();
```

Is this using Linq-to-Objects or something else? If you need to keep it as an `Expression` because the `Expression` gets converted into something else (like a SQL call), you can use [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)'s `AsExpandable` like so:

```
public static Expression<Func<User,int>> RoleCount()
{
    return u => u.Roles.Count();
}

public static void DoStuff()
{
    var roleCounter = RoleCount();

    var query = users.AsExpandable()
                     .Select(u => roleCounter.Invoke(u));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It using LINQ to Entities. Trying to check your solution but so far getting "'roleCounter' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'"

Comment: only difference is that I am doing not "users.AsExpandable()
                     .Select(u => roleCounter(u))" as it your axample but users.AsExpandable().Select(u => new MyClass { RoleCount = roleCounter(u) })

Comment: @Vladimirs I fixed a trivial error in Ocelot's code.  You cannot actually invoke the expression using the invoke operator, you need to use an extension method from LinqKit.

Comment: Ohhh thank you gods of expressions that works like a charm. only key thing is .AsExpandable()

Comment: @Servy Only one thing I am concerned about is performance. Should I worried .AsExpandable() performance?

Answer (score 1):

We can create a `Combine` method that is able to take a selector for an object and then another selector that also takes the output of the first selector to produce a final result:

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Combine<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], param)
        .Replace(second.Parameters[1], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

This uses the following helper method to replace all instance of one expression with another:

```
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}

public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
```

Now we can write:

```
Expression<Func<User, int>> userExpression = x => x.Roles.Count()

var query = users.Select(userExpression.Combine((x, count) => 
    new OneMoreAnotherClass { AnotherProperty = count});
```

Comment: Thanks you for response. Haven't tried that as it over-complicated, but will definitely play with that at some point

Comment: @Vladimirs It's dramatically simpler than adding an entirely new external library to perform the operation.  That library that you're bringing in has quite a lot of code and complexity within it.

Comment: Agree, but I already had LinqKit so @Ocelot20 solution fit me better. I really appreciate your effort and I up-voted all your useful comments, but probably will leave Ocelot20's answer because it seems much easier for me. Thank you again =)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with a closure:

```
User x = z; // assign local value 
var countX = () => x.Roles.Count();
```

now this will work:

```
users.Select(x => new AnotherClass { RoleCount = countX() })
```

Comment: But he doesn't have a single user to close over.  He wants to get the count of the user represented by the current user in the `Select`.

Comment: @Servy - That is not how I read the question.  I see that is the question everyone is answering, I'm answering one about closures.  *shrug*.  We'll see what he is trying to do when we get some feedback.

Comment: Sorry if I confused you with my English. Thank you for efforts but that is not working: System.NotSupportedException: The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: hmmm... not sure what is going on @Vladimirs -- I'd have to look at the exact code you are running.

Comment: @Hogan What's going on is that you're invoking a delegate within your selector expression, and that's an operation that EF does not support, as the error indicates.